# different ways to join columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I am Joining columns are per below query.
for table MST_INSURANCE  I have joined one singe column with 3 different columns of same table.
Is it the optimal way of joining columns? OR is there any other way of doing this?

```
SELECT GR_NAME,
       COUNT(1),
       SUM(ERD_PAID_INS_AMT * ERD_FACTOR),
       SUM(ERD_INS_ADJUST_AMT * ERD_FACTOR),
       SUM(ERD_INS_WRITEOFF_AMT * ERD_FACTOR)
FROM TRN_ERA_HEAD
     INNER JOIN TRN_ERA_DET ON ERD_ERH_ID = ERH_ID
     INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_HEAD ON ERD_BLH_ID = BLH_ID
     INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_DET ON ERD_BLD_ID = BLD_ID
     INNER JOIN MST_INSURANCE ON (BLH_INS1_ID = IM_ID
                               OR BLH_INS2_ID = IM_ID
                               OR BLH_INS3_ID = IM_ID)
     INNER JOIN MST_GROUPS ON IM_ARGRP_ID = GR_ID
WHERE ERH_TRNTYPE IN ('IN', 'IC')
  AND ERH_BOOL_INACTIVE = 0
  AND ERH_STATUS = 'P'
  AND ERH_DOC_DATE >= @P0
  AND ERH_DOC_DATE <= @P1
GROUP BY GR_NAME
ORDER BY GR_NAME;
```

Alternately I have tried using UNION ALL for joining the columns as per below.
But Finding it difficult to write an optimised query.

```
SELECT GR_NAME,
       COUNT(1),
       SUM(ERD_PAID_INS_AMT * ERD_FACTOR),
       SUM(ERD_INS_ADJUST_AMT * ERD_FACTOR),
       SUM(ERD_INS_WRITEOFF_AMT * ERD_FACTOR)
FROM TRN_ERA_HEAD
     INNER JOIN TRN_ERA_DET ON ERD_ERH_ID = ERH_ID
     INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_HEAD ON ERD_BLH_ID = BLH_ID
     INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_DET ON ERD_BLD_ID = BLD_ID
     INNER JOIN MST_INSURANCE ON (BLH_INS1_ID = IM_ID)
     INNER JOIN MST_GROUPS ON IM_ARGRP_ID = GR_ID
WHERE ERH_TRNTYPE IN ('IN', 'IC')
  AND ERH_BOOL_INACTIVE = 0
  AND ERH_STATUS = 'P'
  AND ERH_DOC_DATE >= @P0
  AND ERH_DOC_DATE <= @P1
GROUP BY GR_NAME
UNION ALL
SELECT GR_NAME,
       COUNT(1),
       SUM(ERD_PAID_INS_AMT * ERD_FACTOR),
       SUM(ERD_INS_ADJUST_AMT * ERD_FACTOR),
       SUM(ERD_INS_WRITEOFF_AMT * ERD_FACTOR)
FROM TRN_ERA_HEAD
     INNER JOIN TRN_ERA_DET ON ERD_ERH_ID = ERH_ID
     INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_HEAD ON ERD_BLH_ID = BLH_ID
     INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_DET ON ERD_BLD_ID = BLD_ID
     INNER JOIN MST_INSURANCE ON (BLH_INS2_ID = IM_ID)
     INNER JOIN MST_GROUPS ON IM_ARGRP_ID = GR_ID
WHERE ERH_TRNTYPE IN ('IN', 'IC')
  AND ERH_BOOL_INACTIVE = 0
  AND ERH_STATUS = 'P'
  AND ERH_DOC_DATE >= @P0
  AND ERH_DOC_DATE <= @P1
GROUP BY GR_NAME
UNION ALL
SELECT GR_NAME,
       COUNT(1),
       SUM(ERD_PAID_INS_AMT * ERD_FACTOR),
       SUM(ERD_INS_ADJUST_AMT * ERD_FACTOR),
       SUM(ERD_INS_WRITEOFF_AMT * ERD_FACTOR)
FROM TRN_ERA_HEAD
     INNER JOIN TRN_ERA_DET ON ERD_ERH_ID = ERH_ID
     INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_HEAD ON ERD_BLH_ID = BLH_ID
     INNER JOIN TRN_BILLING_DET ON ERD_BLD_ID = BLD_ID
     INNER JOIN MST_INSURANCE ON (BLH_INS3_ID = IM_ID)
     INNER JOIN MST_GROUPS ON IM_ARGRP_ID = GR_ID
WHERE ERH_TRNTYPE IN ('IN', 'IC')
  AND ERH_BOOL_INACTIVE = 0
  AND ERH_STATUS = 'P'
  AND ERH_DOC_DATE >= @P0
  AND ERH_DOC_DATE <= @P1
GROUP BY GR_NAME
ORDER BY GR_NAME
```

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think your first query is sub-optimal? Also please publish an execution plan and the DDLs for the tables NB in queries with multiple tables it's useful to include the table name or alias for all the columns so we can see where they live..

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do, and what constraints you have. If both legs of the join(s) are unique, your first attempt is likely efficient. Not sure what your union query is supposed to add, it looks like the legs are copies of each other?

If the legs of the join(s) are not unique, you risk ending up with wrong result due to the "multiplier" effect. See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TkQXVOGk) for an example of this.

If that is something you are fine with, you need to provide more info (ddl for tables, keys, indexes and insert statements for sample data, access plans for your different attempts.